# 'and' operator in python3

Tags: python-3.x, expression, comparison-operators

I'm pretty new to coding but I though I understood how the 'and' operator worked. In the example I provided I would have thought that the 'False' statement would get run not the 'True' statement. Can someone enlighten me on why this is not performing as I expected?

```
string = 'asdf'

if 'z' and 's' in string:
    True
else:
    False
```

Comment: You want `'z' in string and 's' in string`

Comment: If you have more than two characters, use a list comprehension: `if all(c in string for c in 'zs'):`

Comment: @Boris I would even do that for two characters to keep the code [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Related: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/4518341)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `and` keyword is part of an *expression* and it should be located between two *subexpressions*. Here you write `'z' and 's' in string` which is interpreted as:

```
('z') and ('s' in string)
```

where the first subexpression, `'z'` is more or less evaluated as `True`, while the second subexpression is a little more sophisticated (in your example, it is also intereted as `True` since `'s'` actually is in `string`.

Combining both subexpressions yields `True` (here).

You certainly wanted to write:

```
if 'z' in string and 's' in string:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to build up on the answer above, to get the correct output that you expect from the if statement you need to specify `if "z" in string and "s" in string` in order for python to compute the correct meaning of what you intend it to do.

```
 string = 'asdf'

 if 'z' in string and 's' in string:
     print("True") 
 else:
     print("False")
```